# Чем является компонент в контексте архитектуры?

Tags: reactjs

Вопрос прост: чем является компонент `ReactComponent` в контексте архитектуры?

Comment: что за _контекст программирования_?

Comment: @Grundy для примера я могу рассматривать Вас в контексте биологического вида, в котором Вы бутите всего-лишь массой, а могу в контексте общества, где Вы будите одним из его звеньев.

Comment: Не стало понятнее. В заголовке тоже стоит сменить

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что отвечающий контингент не способен в полной мере ответить по данной технологии, так как в текущем сегменте она ещё не набрала популярности.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это **представление**, что сказано прямо [на сайте React](http://facebook.github.io/react/):

> Lots of people use React as the V in MVC.

- ***абстрактное***, сам `ReactComponent` в **чистом** виде не используется, но на его базе создаются наследники, которые уже используются напрямую.
- ***рекурсивное (древовидное)***, один компонент может содержать другие компоненты, из-за чего образуется **дерево**, в котором отдельный компонент является **узлом дерева**.

В классах-наследниках им часто придаются и другие архитектурные роли, обычно связанные с обновлением представления, вроде **обработчиков событий**, но это к самому компоненту уже слабо относится.

Comment: @Vas Я джавист, любящий реакт. Но ваш вопрос по-прежнему не понятен. Вы хотите выяснить на какой паттерн похож ReactComponent? К сожалению, архитектурой очень часто называют совсем не то, что нужно. Да, данный ответ на вопрос в его текущем виде отвечает.

Comment: ...так, что-то я не вполне понял, что это сейчас произошло за внезапное изменение точки зрения.

Comment: @Nofate, к своему сожалению сейчас очень спешу и смогу продолжить обсуждение только вечером. Скажите, Вас не затруднит продолжить эту тему позже? К тому же я сделаю несколько примеров чтобы на коде показать что я имею ввиду.

Comment: @D-side я стоял перед выбором спорить или нет. И как Вы заметили, второе все же перевесило :)

Comment: @vas поставив галочку, вы якобы согласились с моим ответом. Я тоже не собирался спорить, вы всегда можете уточнить вопрос и дождаться более точного ответа. А я просто пойду дальше :)